# Getting error on `ng serve` : Error: NG0202

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular10, angular15

I am trying to upgrade an angular application (10 to 15) which basically is creating dynamic Angular components. Now, when I run `ng serve` I am getting the following error:

```
Error: NG0202
    at vn (VM910 main.js:1:19242)
    at Object.v8_Factory [as factory] (ɵfac.js:1:1)
    at P4.hydrate (VM910 main.js:1:59765)
    at P4.get (VM910 main.js:1:58804)
    at Io (VM910 main.js:1:19110)
    at In (VM910 main.js:1:19211)
    at E4.ɵfac [as factory] (VM910 main.js:1:2680700)
    at P4.hydrate (VM910 main.js:1:59765)
    at P4.get (VM910 main.js:1:58804)
    at Io (VM910 main.js:1:19110)

(anonymous) @   VM910 main.js:1
T.invoke    @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
T.run   @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
(anonymous) @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
T.invokeTask    @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
T.runTask   @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
ue  @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
Promise.then (async)        
Te  @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
je  @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
T.scheduleTask  @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
T.scheduleTask  @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
T.scheduleMicroTask @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
Fe  @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
b.then  @   VM887 polyfills.js:23
bootstrapModule @   VM910 main.js:1
6050    @   VM910 main.js:1
a   @   runtime.js:1
fe  @   VM910 main.js:23
(anonymous) @   VM910 main.js:23
n   @   runtime.js:1
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:1
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:1
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:1
```

I have been browsing through the internet for a few days now but in vain. Could anyone please guide could be the reason for this error? Even a generic idea would help.

Please let me know if more information is needed from my side

Comment: The [Angular documentation](https://update.angular.io/) usually advises against jumping major versions. Did you go through the proper steps for upgrading to each version? Then you can verify each version, so from 10 to 11, 11 to 12 etc and verify if everything is working before continuing to the next version.

Comment: as @Ryhazerus states - normally a major version changes brings breaking changes. go back to your code using v 10 and follow https://update.angular.io/?v=10.0-15.0 being careful to test every time you upgrade. that means clearing out node_modules after each upgrade, doing `npm i` and then `ng serve`and ensuring that ALL your testcases work before upgrading to the next version.

Comment: I followed the steps and the issue narrowed down to this function which creates a component class

```
function createComponent() {
  @Component({
      selector: "selected-component",
      template: `<div id="canvas_component"></div>`
   })
  class AngularComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    ...
  }
  ....
}
```
This goes on to create a module too in similar way. and then, compiling the same
compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync
If this class is commented, the error goes away 

Now, i need to find the Angular 15 way for the same